# Despite Await the function is being executed instantly

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am new to Javascript and am facing trouble dealing with Async/Await. Here is my code, as per my understanding adding await puts on hold the function
Here, inside foo, it should put on hold the code at `checker()` and move to running the commands outside `foo`, but instead it executes the `checker()` function before `console.log('the end')`.

```
function checker() {
    console.log('inside checker');
    return "Ok"
}

async function foo() {
    let a = await checker(); // Shouldn't using await here let next line outside foo to execute
    console.log("mid", a);
}
console.log(1);
foo();
console.log('the end');
```

```
// Output coming is: 
//1
//inside checker
//the end
//mid Ok
```

Can someone please tell me what properties are making it to behave this way. I know there's something that I am missing but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `checker` function is not asynchronous, but you also need to do something that is actually async within it.

At the moment, all of the promises are instantly resolved which provides no opportunity for later code to run.

We need to actually create a promise, merely defining a function as async isn't enough unless something inside is returning a promise, so we return a new promise which is resolved by the `setTimeout` callback.

**Note that the timeout period is 0** which is enough to cause the javascript event loop to be invoked, which allows the next statement(s) after calling `foo` to be processed.  Changing this to any positive integer will change the execution time but not the order of events.

```js
function checker() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('Ok'), 0)
    })
}

function foo() {
    let a = checker();
    console.log(new Date(), "mid");
    return a
}

(async () => {
    console.log(new Date(), 'start');
    foo().then(v => console.log(new Date(), 'eventually', v));
    console.log(new Date(), 'the end');
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define your function as async

function checker() {
console.log('inside checker');
return "Ok"
}

It should be

async function checker() {
console.log('inside checker');
return "Ok"
}

Comment: Have tried it already, it is still giving the same output. you can check

Answer (score 0):

`await` tells your code to wait for the function to finish. If you want to continue running without waiting, then you shouldn't use the `await` keyword. `async` also needs to be on the function that you want to run asynchronously, in this case `checker()`

```
async function checker() {
    console.log('inside checker');
    return "Ok"
}

function foo() {
    let a = checker(); 
    console.log("mid", a);
}
console.log(1);
foo();
console.log('the end');
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo` is an async function, ie the code inside it will wait if you use the `await` keyword

But the `foo` function returns a promise. so if you want to wait for `foo` either use

```
await foo();
```

or use

```
foo().then(() => { console.log('the end'); })
```